# reveal.js resize fonts to fit the slide

Tags: reveal.js

I am trying to find out how to auto resize the font to fit my slide.
I am using remote-presentation-controller-master library from 
https://github.com/thehung111/remote-presentation-controller

I have tried to add to the /punlic/css/main.cc

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px), (max-height: 600px) {
    .reveal .slides {
        font-size: 0.82em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px), (max-height: 400px) {
    .reveal .slides {
        font-size: 0.66em;
    }
}
```

But it does not work.
Any idea what I need to do?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always give this a try.

It looks to be pretty similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Change the screen width to test it. 
**Sample:**
https://chunksnbits.github.io/jquery-quickfit/

**Install:** https://github.com/chunksnbits/jquery-quickfit

Comment: That does not work. `$('section').quickfit({'min': 6, 'max': 36})` resizes also the title and text is still flowing out of the slide. `$('section').children().not('h1').not('h2').not('h3').quickfit({'min': 6, 'max': 36})` makes all `li` elements of size 6pt. - May I ask for a complete solution in your answer?